# Skip call macro based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I saw 1 similar question but it didn't address my issue so I decided to post it.

- I have a VBA macro that calls for different macros in a workbook.
- I would like to skip calling specific macros if specific cells in the "Setup" worksheet are empty.
- I came up with the code below. The macro runs fine if the cells are not empty but it actually still calls the macros even when the specific cells are empty.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction!
Thank you in advance.

```
Sub CE_Import()

Dim rng As Range 

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup") 
Set rng = Range("A3") 
For Each cell In rng 
If cell.Value <> "" Then 
Call MSI_Import 
End If

Next

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup") 
Set rng = Range("D3") 
For Each cell In rng 
If cell.Value <> "" Then 
Call IGH_Import 
End If

Next

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup") 
Set rng = Range("G3") 
For Each cell In rng 
If cell.Value <> "" Then 
Call TCell_Import 
End If

Next

Call Hidden_Import

End Sub
'''
```

Comment: Your `Set rng` is always single cell. So, why you are using for each loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly reduce your current code.

What I'm unsure about is if the later methods are meant to be called even if the previous methods weren't.

E.g. do you want `IGH_Import` or `Hidden_Import` to be called even if `MSI_Import` wasn't called? I think that may be the root of your issue, either that or those cells aren't really empty.

```
Sub CE_Import()

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup").Range("A3").Value2 <> "" Then Call MSI_Import
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup").Range("D3").Value2 <> "" Then Call IGH_Import 
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup").Range("G3").Value2 <> "" Then Call TCell_Import 

Call Hidden_Import

End Sub
```

Comment: This is much more elegant!
Yes, the idea was to call the other macros even if the previous one wasn't called. Your proposed code worked perfectly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try below sub-

```
Sub CE_Import()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup")

    If ws.Range("A3") <> "" Then
        Call MSI_Import
    End If
    
    If ws.Range("D3") <> "" Then
        Call IGH_Import
    End If
    
    If ws.Range("G3") <> "" Then
        Call TCell_Import
    End If

    Call Hidden_Import
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I guess i was not clear enough and has suggested by jamheadart, the macros had to be called regardless of the fact that the previous cell was empty or not. Your code was working but skipping to the last macro if one of the cells was empty. But the syntax is interesting and I will probably be able to re-use it. Thank you!

Comment: Harun24hr code is functionally the same as jamheadart 's. Just the Ifs are not one-lined and the worksheet is put into a variable (and the default .Value is omitted). You should get the same results if applied to the same inputs.

Comment: The code wasn't the same initially, he's changed it. It was one `if elseif elseif else` statement.